# Wordpress Display Post Title, Custom Fields in Table

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sorry for such a newbie question as I'm just starting to learn php. I'm trying to create a table that pulls data from a custom post type and repeat with additional posts from the same post type. I created the first part with some php but I'd want this to repeat for the custom post type.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'degrees', 'Degrees Offered: ', ', ' ); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'program_location', 'Program Location(s): ', ', ' ); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'institution_type', 'Institution Type: ', ', ' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Post 2 Title</td>
   <td>Post 2 Degrees Offered</td>
   <td>Post 2 Program Locations</td>
   <td>Post 2 Institution Type</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Post 3 Title</td>
   <td>Post 3 Degrees Offered</td>
   <td>Post 3 Program Locations</td>
   <td>Post 3 Institution Type</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into wp_query in the wordpress CODEX, it lets you specific get post_types and iterate through them.

Ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Sample Code:

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
        // ---------------------
        // YOUR TABLE LOGIC HERE
        // ---------------------
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: Thank you Diego! I think my biggest sense of confusion is how to repeat a html table with pulled wordpress content.